# How to add and delete users from input file to linux system?

Tags: c++, linux, inputstream

My program is supposed to add 100 users and passwords. However I'm having difficulty (I'll be posting the output and the input file) as well. What is supposed to happen is that a user name is taken from the file and the password is as well (it's from their id number). The format would be like user: jacob password: se-123456. However, it seems that user does not exist. Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "Hello world." << endl;
//system("mkdir user1"); 
string anyCommand="", name, userpassword;
 ifstream myfile ("userNames1000.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
   //code to open a file
 {
  while ( getline (myfile,anyCommand) )
    {
     for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {

        stringstream temp;
        temp << i;
        name = "user";
        name += temp.str();  

        //useradd vs. userdel
        anyCommand = "useradd " + name;

        cout << anyCommand << endl;
        //system(anyCommand.c_str());

        anyCommand = ""; 
        userpassword = "se- " ;

         //set the command, e.g., system("echo john:se-2014 |chpasswd");
        anyCommand = "echo " + name + ":" + userpassword + " |chpasswd";
        cout << anyCommand << endl;
        system(anyCommand.c_str());

        }

        myfile.close();

        }


  }     
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;


}
```

Here's what's going on when I run the program:

```
    Hello World
    useradd user0
    echo user0:se-  | chpasswd
    chpasswd: line 1: user 'user0' does not exist
    chpasswd: error detected, changes ignored
    useradd user1
    echo user1:se-  | chpasswd
    chpasswd: line 1: user 'user1' does not exist
    chpasswd: error detected, changes ignored
    useradd user2
    echo user2:se-  | chpasswd
    chpasswd: line 1: user 'user2' does not exist
    chpasswd: error detected, changes ignored
```

Then it goes on until it reaches 100; the same error keeps going. I've got a feeling that I'm going in the right direction, I just need some assistance into what I need to fix.

Here's an example of what's in the input file.

```
Mary:20153

Lindsey:19396

Ashley:17151

Jason:16861
```

Comment: As the log said you try to change password for users that do not existed, you should use [useradd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) if you you want to actually add new users

Answer (score 0):

You commented out a important line (as mentioned in the comment by A.Flaischer):

```
anyCommand = "useradd " + name;

cout << anyCommand << endl;
//system(anyCommand.c_str());
```

Your program on the other hand seems not to do what you think it should to. It works from user0 to user99, but you mentioned the example input file. This input file will not be processed (correctly).

As C++ is may be your favorite language, a shell script will be the easiest way to accomplish your task.